# Batch ren command to keep file extension and accommodating filenames with "."

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a script the renames files keeping its file extension as follows:

```
ren path\one.* two.*
ren path\three.* four.*
```

which works fine for file names above without "." in its name, however when i
have a file with the name for example "does.not.work".
With the script:

```
ren path\does.not.work.* test.*
```

it will rename it as "test.not.work.EXT".

The ren command is automatically generated elsewhere to rename large amounts of different files.
So manually changing the script to something like:

```
ren path\does.not.work.txt test.txt
```

is impractical.
How could I structure the ren code to accommodate files that contain "."?

Comment: use a for loop to do that. `for %%i in (does.not.work.*) do ren "%%~i" "test%%~xi"`

Comment: Take a look at this very interesting post [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards? \[Super User\]](https://superuser.com/q/475874)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a for loop:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (does.not.work.*) do ren "%%~i" "test%%~xi"
```

Obviously you can use a single for loop to achieve this for all the file renames, there are a few ways by using `if` statements which will mean you'll be setting variables in the for loop, here is one way by utilizing `findstr` and the resulting `errorlevel` to rename according to what it finds, you'll need to fine tune it though as a search for `su` will also match in `sudo` so read up on `findstr /?` to see how you can either use regular expression or word boundaries to achieve exact search results:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
    echo %%~ni | findstr "one" && ren "%%~i" "two%%~xi"
    echo %%~ni | findstr "three" && ren "%%~i" "four%%~xi"
    echo %%~ni | findstr "does.not.work" && ren "%%~i" "test%%~xi"
)
```